# Skype login can not be executed on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: login, skype

I got ubuntu 13.10 release a couple of days back, and there is some bugs like allways with every new distro version after realisation. But anyway, that bugs are not really any problem or something hard to fix, but only one problem, that I can not solve is my skype. Opening skype every time is as opening it for a first time, when you are prompted to accept license and login.

I get this even after I open it for first time after starting machine, or right after restarting it. I go to login screen, type my credentials, and I get message:

> We cant open skype! You are already signed in on this computer. Please
>   sign out and try again.

How can I solve this ?

Any help will be really useful as I am person who lives 3000km from home and use skype every day.

Comment: i found a way trough terminal, if someone else have this problem, and before we got some answer how to fix it, open terminal and type:

**(sudo) echo <username> <password> | skype --pipelogin**

hope this helps to someone at this time...

Comment: add this as the answer as it solves your problem.

Comment: no it does not, it is just temporary solution what to do, and not a fix of given bug.

Comment: Just delete .Skype directory in /home/yourUserName/.Skype Then restart skype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on my own how to fix this problem. Completely accidentally. I was about to make some changes in allowed software on system and i opened Software & Updates from dash. So, first go to dash and search for:

> Software & Updates

and open it. Then i went under tab

> Other Software

and what i saw, gave me an answer. As Skype is

> Canonical partners application

you must check it to enable, also i am not sure about:

> Canonical partners (Source code)

but check it as well.

As Canonical partners software was not allowed, that is why on every skype launch it pops EULA license, as i just tryed every time to install it, and it was not allowed.

After all, just close Software and Update, and wait until it completes changes and updates. After that, just launch Skype, and if problem still exists, simple reinstallation will fix it.

Hope this helps.